# __gc method for a malloced userdata in lua?

Tags: c, lua

I have `malloc`'ed a userdata in my C api. Where should I free that?

Should I write a `__gc` method for that userdata, and `free` it inside? If yes, is not it a double free as garbage collector will also free it?

Comment: Unless specifically designed with that in mind, the garbage collector has no idea about your pointer.

Comment: i didnt gert you ,sorry. i undersyand we dont need to bother if we use lua_newuserdata to create . but i use malloc for it in c.

Comment: Can you show some code please? Are you using lightudata or fulludata? First isn't managed by lua while the second is.

Answer (score 3):

Only full userdata can have gc methods and full userdata must be created using `lua_newuserdata`.

Light userdata is just a pointer in C space and so must be managed by the C host. Light userdata cannot have gc methods.

Comment: I am trying to add new userdata of int64. it is full userdata.In my C api i am creating it using malloc and pushing to stack.

Comment: @Nikole, if you need int64 in Lua try this library: http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lint64.

Answer (score 1):

Lua's garbage collector has no idea that you allocated some memory with malloc, so it will not free it for you.

Lua will free the memory that Lua allocated. You must free the memory that you allocated.

Comment: OK, but I think the OP is asking how you know when it is safe to do this. There are several scenarios: you create a userdata which your own C code does not use so it is under pure Lua management but the userdatum uses resources that it must release; OR, you malloc a struct which also keeps valuable resources and you use this struct in your program as well as in Lua state, in which case you don't want to free it if it is still in use by Lua, but you do want to free it as soon as it is no longer in use by either Lua or your C code.